# Multiple files and Object Oriented Programming

Tags: c++, oop, class, class-design

In my application, I use multiple files, each file contains a class, is it a good idea to gather all C++ files (implementation of all classes) in one file and gather all headers in another file, or this is not good for some reason but code organizing ?

Comment: How can C files contain classes since the `class` keyword isn't supported in the C language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keeping declarations and definitions organized in to separate but related translation units can help to decrease compilation times.

And don't disregard the value of keeping things organized for humans too!  Software can consist of many thousand different objects, functions, and other parts. Keep it as simple as possible (but no simpler)!

Comment: +1 - I agree. It's better to split the code up so that it is easily maintainable then to worry about the number of files! I hate it when I have to make changes to monolithic, legacy code, as finding anything takes too long. Also if under change control it's easier to guage what functionality has changed if classes are split into their own source and header files.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep declaration and definitions of a class in the corresponding files, they need only to be recompiled when you made changes in these class. Also changes in one class only requires relinking of the changed class against the classes which depend on it. Therefore it decreases compile time.

It makes it also much more easier to debug, as the compilation errors can be traced back to one file.

There is no advantage to concatenate all files in one, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it really doesn't matter so much.  In some languages, such as Java, the compiler requires that every class be in a separate file, but as long as you make sure that the different files reference each other there is no reason either way.

Answer (score 0):

Perfectly agree with other answers, and I would like to add my piece :

Breaking into several files also make it easier when using an editor. You can then use several tabs. (Imagine if your browser displayed all your pages one after another in one window only !)

It is even acceptable to break a class implementation in several files if the implementation is big.

On the other hand, there are sometimes reasons to put several classes in one file, for example when those classes are small and/or very highly related. For example a *FooObject* and its *FooAllocator*, or a *FooObject* and its small *FooSubObject* used only by him.